# after enabled touch id successfully how to login with touch id while open app next time

Tags: swift

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

    for family in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("\(family)")
        for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
            print("   \(name)")
        }
    }
    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userEmail") != nil {
        let RegisterUser = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "RegisterUser") as? NSDictionary ?? [:]

        if RegisterUser.object(forKey: "AddAddress") as? String ?? "" == "0" {
            initialViewController  = Registration_iPohoneVC(nibName:"Registration_iPohoneVC",bundle:nil)
        }else if RegisterUser.object(forKey: "JobInfo") as? String ?? "" == "0" {
            initialViewController  = JobInfo_iPohoneVC(nibName:"JobInfo_iPohoneVC",bundle:nil)
        }else if RegisterUser.object(forKey: "UploadResume") as? String ?? "" == "0" {
            initialViewController  = Uploadresume_iPhoneVC1(nibName:"Uploadresume_iPhoneVC1",bundle:nil)
        }else if RegisterUser.object(forKey: "UploadVideo") as? String ?? "" == "0" {
            initialViewController  = Createvideo_iPhoneVC(nibName:"Createvideo_iPhoneVC",bundle:nil)
        }else {
            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Touchid") as? Bool ?? false == true {
                let context = LAContext()
                var error: NSError?
                if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
                    let reason = "Touch the home button with your finger to LogIn."
                    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply:
                        {(succes, error) in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                if succes {
                                    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Touchid") as? Bool ?? false == true {
                                        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "PlanSelected") as? Int ?? 0 == 90 {
                                            self.initialViewController  = Homescreen_iPhoneVC(nibName:"Homescreen_iPhoneVC",bundle:nil)
                                        }else {
                                            self.initialViewController  = Homescreen6_iPhoneVC(nibName:"Homescreen6_iPhoneVC",bundle:nil)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else {
                                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Touch ID Authentication Failed", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
                                        UIAlertAction in
                                        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "userEmail")
                                        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "userPassword")
                                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                                        self.initialViewController  = Login_iPhoneVC(nibName:"Login_iPhoneVC",bundle:nil)
                                        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
                                        self.window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
                                        self.window!.rootViewController = appdelegate!.initialViewController!
                                        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
                                    }
                                    alertController.addAction(okAction)
                                    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            }
                    })
                }else {
                    print("touch id not available...")
                }
            }else {
                if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "PlanSelected") as? Int ?? 0 == 90 {
                    self.initialViewController  = Homescreen_iPhoneVC(nibName:"Homescreen_iPhoneVC",bundle:nil)
                }else {
                    self.initialViewController  = Homescreen6_iPhoneVC(nibName:"Homescreen6_iPhoneVC",bundle:nil)
                }
            }
        }
        let navigationcontroller = UINavigationController()
        navigationcontroller.viewControllers = [appdelegate!.initialViewController!]
        navigationcontroller.navigationBar.barTintColor = AppBG1Color
        navigationcontroller.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self as UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
        navigationcontroller.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
        window!.rootViewController = navigationcontroller
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }else {
        initialViewController = Login_iPhoneVC(nibName: "Login_iPhoneVC", bundle: nil)
        let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
        window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard(_:)))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    window?.rootViewController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return true
}
```

here is my Appdelegate code, in my else condition i want first touch id popup for user to Ask touch the home button to login while user has Already enabled touch id but it will crash directly, i want while user has Already enabled touch id then he can Access App with touch every time he open App Again. if Anyone can help it would be greatful Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If he enabled touch id set bollean flag as UserDefaults, and next time he runs the app read it, if its *true* then let him use touch id, if not - need to ask him.

P.S.You should probably move all this logic to SceneDelegate :) AppDelegate isn't place for this things anymore